Raspberry Pi Pico Wでhttp requestすると401エラーになる
Raspberry Pi Pico WでWiFi経由でHTTPリクエストすると401で返ってきます。
MicroPython + VSCodeの環境で動作させています。
具体的には、スイッチボットの制御をしようとしており、urequestsをimportしてpostやgetでスイッチボットAPIを要求しています。
実際、VSCode上でRunして実行すると正常にリクエストできており、制御できているのですが、
同じコードのmain.pyをラズパイに入れて、自動起動にすると401エラーになります。
WiFiの接続は問題なさそうなのですが、httpリクエストがエラーになります。
原因が分からず、ご教授頂ければと思います。

エラーが出ている個所の http request のコードを記載いただければ、回答がつきやすくなると思います。

自己解決しました。
下記、postする自前の関数で要求しているのですが、
引数のapiHeaderを渡す際に、HMACによる署名の情報が固定になっていました。
要求する際に毎度署名情報を作って渡すことで解決しました。
def request_post_to_wifi(apiHeader, url, payload):
    try:
        response = urequests.post(url, headers=apiHeader, json=payload)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
        return None

これが、VSCodeによる実行だと毎回問題ない理由は分かりませんが。。。
